# MySQL Join with And condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I am using this SQL code to select random entries from a question table.

I would like to add a condition to this query. Basically the table has a user id record to keep track of who added the question. This id record shall now be used on conjunction with the Join Query.

Basically: Select random question entry AND verify it belongs to the given user id.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Questions JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                    (SELECT MAX(Question_ID)
                       FROM Questions )) AS Question_ID
        ) AS r2
       USING (Question_ID) ;
```

I tried adding the condition like this:

```
And UID='$user_ID'
```

However I am getting a blank page as a result so I guess by adding the condition like this, I am messing up the entire query. Basically, I can't figure up how to put the condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Questions JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                    (SELECT MAX(Question_ID)
                       FROM Questions WHERE UID='$user_ID')) AS Question_ID
        ) AS r2
       USING (Question_ID) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `''` quotes in PHP denotes a literal string whereas `""` input variables, they're not interchangeable. If using `''`'s you can input variables by doing `'{$var}'`.

If your table is very large it would be slow to run a RAND() over it and would be better to pass a random id generated in PHP.

Random from PHP:

```
SELECT *
FROM Questions as q
WHERE q.UID = $user_ID AND q.ID = $randomID;\
```

Random from SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Questions as q
WHERE q.UID = $user_ID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```